# How to save multiple plotted csv files? FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, csv, listdir

I'm trying to plot and save all the plotted figures of csv files in different folders. These folders are in a parent folder called "Logs-Zip", which is in my working directory. It actually works for one single csv file. However when I use a nested loop to save all the plotted figures I get get an error. I acces these csv files using `os.listdir(os.path.join(path, folder))`. After running I get the saved figure of the first csv file and

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'01WEA85069_2021-06-02_19-26-56_ST193.csv'.
```

This csv file corresponds to second csv file in the iteration.

All csv files have the same header and here is the first one: [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yLiilNuaFrX6ZslEVCvF94H1mKRL-Yi3/view?usp=sharing)

I can read the file names like:

```
01WEA82849_2021-05-21_08-50-02_ST193.csv
01WEA85069_2021-06-02_19-26-56_ST193.csv
..
```

but I think I have a problem with passing the path for the files after the first one. What am I missing actually? Thanks in advance!

here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import sqrt
import os

try:
    path = r"C:\Users\aliha\PycharmProjects\nordex\Logs-Zip"

    for folder in os.listdir(path):
        for csv_file_name in os.listdir(os.path.join(path, folder)):

            data = pd.read_csv((csv_file_name), usecols=['$Time', 'TR_A_00', 'TR_A_01', 'TR_A_02', 'TR_A_07', 'TR_A_08'])

            v12 = data['TR_A_00']
            v23 = data['TR_A_01']
            v31 = data['TR_A_02']

            A = ((v12 ** 2) + (v23 ** 2) + (v31 ** 2)) / 2
            B = ((v12 ** 2) * (v23 ** 2) + (v23 ** 2) * (v31 ** 2) + (v31 ** 2) * (v12 ** 2)) / 2
            C = ((v12 ** 2) * (v12 ** 2) + (v23 ** 2) * (v23 ** 2) + (v31 ** 2) * (v31 ** 2)) / 4
            a = B - C
            M = (1 / sqrt(3)) * sqrt(A + sqrt(3) * a.apply(lambda x: (sqrt(x))))
            G = (1 / sqrt(3)) * sqrt(A - sqrt(3) * a.apply(lambda x: (sqrt(x))))

            df3 = pd.read_csv(csv_file_name)
            new_column = pd.DataFrame({'M': M, 'G': G})
            df3 = df3.merge(new_column, left_index=True, right_index=True)
            df3.to_csv((csv_file_name), index=False)

            data = pd.read_csv((csv_file_name),usecols=['$Time', 'TR_A_00', 'TR_A_01', 'TR_A_02', 'TR_A_07', 'TR_A_08', 'M', 'G'])

            df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['$Time', 'TR_A_00', 'TR_A_01', 'TR_A_02'])
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['$Time', 'M', 'G'])
            df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['$Time', 'TR_A_07'])
            df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['$Time', 'TR_A_08'])

            fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=1)
            fig.suptitle((csv_file_name))
            df.plot(ax=axes[0], grid=True, x='$Time', y=['TR_A_00', 'TR_A_01', 'TR_A_02'])
            df1.plot(ax=axes[1], grid=True, x='$Time', y=['M', 'G'])
            df2.plot(ax=axes[2], grid=True, x='$Time', y='TR_A_07')
            df3.plot(ax=axes[3], grid=True, x='$Time', y='TR_A_08')
            fig.tight_layout()
            plt.savefig(f'{csv_file_name}.png', dpi=150)

except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: How can you list files inside a file? You need to check if the path is a directory are not

Comment: `listdir` gives only filename and you have to join it with folder - `read_csv( os.path.join(path, folder, csv_file_name) )`

Comment: you could at least display error `except ValueError as ex: print(ex)`. One day you may have problem with `ValueError` and you will wondering why program doesn't work without error messages.

Comment: you read the same file 3 times - it is waste of time - but you could read it only once and use many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common mistake.

`listdir` gives only filename and you have to `join` with `folder`

```
        fullpath = os.path.join(path, folder, csv_file_name)

        data = pd.read_csv(fullpath)
```

Comment: Thank you @furas! I also consider your notes.